# [ArcGIS toolbars.Draw.POLYGON ]Object #<BarProp> has no method 'activate'

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, toolbar

I am facing this error while activating the toolbar.

This is my body code

```
  <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" onClick="toolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Draw.POLYGON); map.hideZoomSlider();">Polygon</button>
```

And this is the javascript i am loading:

```
 //Polygon & FreeHand Polygon------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      var toolbar, symbol, geomTask;

        function createToolbar(map) {
            toolbar = new esri.toolbars.Draw(map);
            dojo.connect(toolbar, "onDrawEnd", addToMap);
        }

    dojo.require("esri.tasks.geometry");
    dojo.require("esri.toolbars.draw");

      function addToMap(geometry) {

            switch (geometry.type) {

                case "polygon":
                    var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol
                    (esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol
                    (esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DASHDOT, new dojo.Color([255, 0, 0]), 2), new dojo.Color([255, 255, 0, 0.25]));

                    break;

            }
            var graphic = new esri.Graphic(geometry, symbol);
            map.graphics.add(graphic);

            var theme = document.getElementById('SelectTheme').value;
            var token = "xkg8VRu6Ol+gMH+SUamkRIEB7fKzhwMvfMo/2U8UJcFhdvR4yN1GutmUIA3A6r3LDhot215OVVkZvNRzjl28TNUZgYFSswOi";
            var queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("http://www.onemap.sg/DataService/Services.svc/" + theme + "?token=" + token);

            var query = new esri.tasks.Query();

            query.geometry = graphic.geometry;
            query.outFields = ["DESCRIPTION"];
            query.geometryType = "";
            query.outSR = "";
            query.returnGeometry = true;
            query.spatialRel = "esriSpatialRelIntersects";
            query.text = "";
            query.where = "";

            //Execute QueryTask
            queryTask.execute(query);
            dojo.connect(queryTask, "onComplete", function (fset) {
                //create symbol for selected features


                //                var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol();
                //                symbol.style = esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE;
                if (theme == "Disability") {

                    var symbol = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol('/images/disability.jpg', 25, 25);

                    symbol.setColor(new dojo.Color([255, 255, 255, 1]));
                }
                else if (theme == "VoluntaryWelfareOrgs") {

                    var symbol = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol('/images/Welfare.jpg', 25, 25);

                    symbol.setColor(new dojo.Color([1, 1, 1, 1]));
                }
                 else if (theme == "ElderCare") {

                    var symbol = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol('/images/elder.jpg', 25, 25);

                    symbol.setColor(new dojo.Color([1, 1, 1, 1]));
                }
                else if (theme == "CommuinityClubs") {

                    var symbol = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol('/images/ramp.jpg', 25, 25);

                    symbol.setColor(new dojo.Color([255, 255, 255, 255]));
                }

                var infoTemplate = new esri.InfoTemplate();
                infoTemplate.setTitle(theme);
                var resultFeatures = fset.features;
                for (var i = 0, il = resultFeatures.length; i < il; i++) {
                    var graphic = resultFeatures[i];
                    graphic.setSymbol(symbol);
                    graphic.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);
                    OneMap.map.graphics.add(graphic);
                }
            }

            );
        }
```

can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Based on how your code looks, your toolbar variable needs to be global. The error makes it look like your toolbar variable is not global or something else is overwriting it. This is one of the reasons [you shouldn't use an element's onClick attribute to set up event listeners](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html).

Take a look at either the [Add graphics to a map](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/graphics_add.html) or the [Drawing tools sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/toolbar_draw.html) for examples you can follow.